# Limited connection whenever I connect to a Wi-Fi network outside the company

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, network-adapter, domain

Whenever I connect my work laptop to a wireless network outside of my company, the connection shows as *Limited*, and there is no internet access.

I have tried several times by disabling/enabling the network adapter, restarting the computer... without success. Sometimes, after a while, without taking any action, it shows fine, and I have internet access. But can pass 2 hours before this happens.

My computer is under a domain network, but I don't think that's the problem, because I can successfuly connect other computers belonging to same domain to other networks.

I'm running `Windows 8 Pro` and my network adapter is the following:

> Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter

Any idea of which is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: I'm guessing your company has locked down the name server setting to prevent this, and restrict how you can access the internet while on the company net.

Comment: @DanielRHicks but this only happens with my computer, not with others. Additionaly, we don't have any restrictions to access the internet.

Comment: Check your name server settings.